# BSOD occurring in ERAM (Open Source RAMDisk driver)

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, ram, disk

When I use it (its source code is available at https://github.com/Zero3K/ERAM) in a Windows 10 64-bit virtual machine (in driver signature enforcement disabled mode) with it configured to use 100 MB for a RAM Disk and is set as a fixed disk via its cpl, I get a FAT_FILE_SYSTEM blue screen that does not happen in a Windows 7 64-bit virtual machine. Maybe someone could look at its source code to see what is causing it and then offer a fix.

Comment: why do you ask here if [you already reported it on github](https://github.com/Zero3K/ERAM/issues/2)?

Comment: Because no one has responded to it yet.

Comment: so the tool is dead, switch to a different one.

Comment: But it can be brought back to life since its source is available.

Comment: Now I am getting a MEMORY_MANAGEMENT BSOD with no dump being made when I use a developer's signed version of it.

Comment: I have managed to get an analysis of the mentioned BSOD. It can be viewed by going to https://pastebin.com/MUBtSmcg.

Comment: a value in line 3017 is Null so you get the BSOD

Comment: I am having a conversation with a guy on IRC who also agrees that the value used in that line is wrong. Maybe he can give me a replacement that works.

Comment: He didn't offer any help.

Comment: I can't help you. switch to a different tool.

Comment: Maybe someone else can. By the way, a list of defects found when building it with WDK 7.1.0 can be found at https://pastebin.com/tuf48eHn.

Comment: I managed to fix the BSODs thanks to the help of a member of community.osr.com. Now I am getting some after removing the 4 GB limit and testing one that has a size of 6 GB. You can see the pull request with the changes I did by going to https://github.com/Zero3K/ERAM/pull/10.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a bug report, not a programming question.

Comment: Well, it still involves code. Code that I can change when someone gives me advice.

Comment: The BSODs are no longer occurring thanks to a developer that is in an IRC channel that I was in. Now I just want someone to sign it or help me with signing and packaging it when I get money and buy the certificate and dongle.